# Thrust: Operator '*' is not supported

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have the following function for filling the vector t with steps from -time/2 to time/2 and stepsize dt:

```
#define THRUST_PREC thrust::complex<double>
__host__ void generate_time(thrust::device_vector<THRUST_PREC> *t, const double dt, const double time)
{
    THRUST_PREC start = -time / 2.0;
    THRUST_PREC step = dt;
    thrust::sequence((*t).begin(), (*t).end(), start, step);
}
```

When compiling, I get `error : no operator "*" matches these operands`. Why? Is there a way to fill the vector as I do, or should I fill it in the old way (aka loop)?

Edit: Full error: `Error 1  error : no operator "*" matches these operands  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include\thrust\system\detail\generic\sequence.inl   48  1   FFT_test`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and provide the *entire set of errors and notes* from the compiler not just an exerpt.  If you understood the error message you would not need to ask here, and if you do not understand why do you think the summary is sufficient?  I mean, I cannot believe it did not give you the line the error occurred on.

Comment: @Yakk: I added the full error, that is all I get in MSVC...

Comment: I do not know, I copied the error directly from MSVC. When removing/commenting this function, the error is gone. When adding/uncommenting it, I get the error listed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug of `thrust::complex`. The multiply operation between `const thrust:complex<double>` and `signed long` is not defined.

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/generic/sequence.inl(48):
error: no operator "*" matches these operands
             operand types are: const thrust::complex<double> * signed long
           detected during:
           ....
```

But strangely, you could use `thrust::transform` instead. The following code works.

```
#define THRUST_PREC thrust::complex<double>
__host__ void generate_time(thrust::device_vector<THRUST_PREC> *t, const double dt, const double time)
{
  THRUST_PREC start = -time / 2.0;
  THRUST_PREC step = dt;
  thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                    thrust::make_counting_iterator(0) + t->size(),
                    t->begin(),
                    start + step * _1);
}
```

In either way, the internal implementation uses an index (of the type `signed long` in `thrust::sequence`) to calculate the desired sequence with the expression

```
start + step * index;
```

The thing prevents `thrust::sequence` from working is that `operator *(...)` is not well overloaded.

```
thrust::complex<double> a(1,1);
double double_b = 4;
float float_b = 4;
int int_b = 4;
long long_b = 4;

a *= double_b; // ok
a *= float_b;  // ok
a *= int_b;    // ok
a *= long_b;   // ok

std::cout << a * double_b << std::endl; // ok
std::cout << a * float_b << std::endl;  // error
std::cout << a * int_b << std::endl;    // error
std::cout << a * long_b << std::endl;   // error
```

Comment: I do not get this output as error message, only the first part I posted. Why is there a signed long in it anyway?

Comment: You could also define it yourself.  :)

Comment: @arc_lupus we use different compilers.

Comment: Indeed it is. I've fixed this; the fix will be available in CUDA 9.2.